# In try catch statement catch is not being run after error inside async inside function. Javscript

Tags: javascript, error-handling, try-catch

I've simplified it down here but this is basically what's going on, I have a function that runs an async function that has a try-catch block in it. Inside that, there is another function that gets run but it throws an error. That error isn't being caught by the catch block. Is there any way to fix that?

I need the error to be thrown inside func2 and to be caught by that catch block.

```
func1();
function func1(){
  (async () => {
    try {
      console.log("checkpoint 1");
      func2();
      async function func2(){
        lalalala; // error here
      }
    } catch {
      console.log("error"); // This never gets run
    }
  })();
}
```

Comment: You need to `await`, if you want `try/catch`. If you're using the Promise API, you need `func2().catch()`

Comment: In this sample, the innermost function is never executed…?!

Comment: @VLAZ, is there any way to go from func2().catch() and to get the other catch to run, the one that console.log("error")

Comment: @deceze it is, but the execution is *before* the declaration. It took me a moment, as well.

Comment: @VLAZ Aah… I'm not really sure why the function declaration is necessary at all, it seems superfluous…

Comment: @JackBashed ideally, you don't want to mix Promise API and `await`. Use one or the other because there is no benefit in having both. In your case, seems you just want `await func2()`

Comment: @deceze simplified example perhaps. Might just be a bit too simplified. I wouldn't really hold it against it - it serves its purpose as an illustration.